# Must provide either 'fields' or 'layoutTypes' on a flow screen lookup

Tags: visual-workflow, lookup

I'm trying to build a flow with a lookup component. However, I'm always getting the error :

```
Must provide either 'fields' or 'layoutTypes' when providing childRelationships param.
```

[image]

Here are the parameters of my flow component.

[image]

It seems that all field API Name, Object API Name and RecordId fields are OK, as I doubled checked it.

Do you have any idea about why this error arises ?

Comment: It might be related to the fact that I have a Lookup Filter on this lookup field. When deactivation this lookup filter, everything seems to work fine

Answer (score 0):

I had this same issue but without lookup filters. What I had to do for the record Id was use a variable to get the record providing the existing value then reference the field that has the value I wanted. Just referencing the recordId didn't work.

So, for example, say you have a variable that gets the Customer__c called getCustomer to get the reference record. For Record Id you'd enter `{!getCustomer.Billing_Contact__c}`